# Keep getting error: ';' expected

Tags: java, onclick, onclicklistener, implements

I keep getting this error "Error:(28, 43) error: ';' expected".

This is the code line where the error is:

```
            public void onClick(View view) implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
```

Comment: Post more code. The line it tells you isn't necessarily the line the actual error is on. I'm guessing you're missing it on the line (or expression) above this code.

Comment: FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                View view = null;
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

Comment: You should correct your question tags, this is java i presume.

Comment: yes, it's java. sorry about not saying.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal statement for sure.

`public void onClick(View view)` states that you define some method. But `implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener` can be included in class/interface definition only. (Like `class A implements B`).

If you are making listener, do this:

```
class MyListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You should fix new errors then. The code line from original post is incorrect.